# Which PKCS#11 function does Oracle Database 11g makes use of?

Tags: database, oracle, security, encryption, cryptography

I am currently in the process of coming up with a PKCS#11 library with minimal functions such that my legacy HSM is able to support the Oracle database 11g transparent data encryption (TDE). I do not want to come up with the complete PKCS#11 library with all the functions since all I need is to support Oracle database. In addition, coding all functions will take too long a development effort and it would be an overkill in doing so.

Does anybody have any ideas as to which PKCS#11 functions does "Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2)" makes use of for supporting TDE with HSM?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of HSM device is it?

Comment: It is an encryption key server for the secure storage of encryption/decryption keys and all cryptographic operations are performed within the confines of the HSM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer is as quoted from [Oracle Forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1127687&stqc=true):

I checked the 11.2 code and you need to implement these functions for use with TDE:

```
C_Initialize
C_GetFunctionList
C_GetInfo
C_GetSlotList
C_OpenSession
C_Login
C_CloseSession
C_Finalize
C_GenerateKey
C_FindObjectsInit
C_FindObjects
C_FindObjectsFinal
C_EncryptInit
C_Encrypt
C_DecryptInit
C_Decrypt
C_CloseSession
```

It is also recommended to implement `C_GenerateKeyPair` so it can be used by wallet manager to create a certificate request

Answer (score 0):

Most probably at least the following:

- C_GetFunctionList
- C_Initialize
- C_GetSlotList
- C_OpenSession
- C_Login
- C_FindObjectsInit
- C_FindObjects
- C_FindObjectsFinal
- C_EncryptInit
- C_Encrypt or
- C_EncryptUpdate
- C_EncryptFinal
- C_DecryptInit
- C_Decrypt or
- C_DecryptUpdate
- C_DecryptFinal

You can use OpenSC [pkcs11-spy](http://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/UsingOpensc) to sniff on Oracle to see which functions it actually uses and with what kind of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I used OpenSC's pkcs11-spy, and find out that Oracle 11g R2 Wallet Manager would also call:
C_GenerateKeyPairs, C_SignInit, and C_Sign during the certificate request process.

Oscar

Comment: How did you use OpenSC pkcs11-spy? Where do you put the library? C:\oracle\extapi\32\hsm\?